# Prevent IE6 visitors

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser, browser-detection

How can I drop the using of IE6 to browse my website ?

Something like : 
 
if ie6 => die
 
I am using ASP.Net
 Thanks

Comment: This is hilarious. =) Just remember that your users may deserve your respect for their decision... or limitations.

Comment: @Miguel - yes they do, but if I don't do that the website well not work properly because I am using a mechanism which depends on XMLHTTPRequests which are not supported in Ie6 .

Comment: @Miguel that maybe true. But this is IE6 we're talking about.

Comment: Do you really believe that [IE6 should be taken into consideration?](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201005-201105) This is hilarious.

Comment: I know that IE6 is a piece of crap these days. But people still uses it. I mean that this kind of move deserves planning, just that.

Comment: @ErickPetru: these are global stats. Corporations have their own stats. Countries have their own stats. Each group have their own stats. It is the job of the manager of the project to know what audience the page will have. Yes I believe it should be taken into consideration, depending on the project type and audience.

Comment: And why you said "this is hilarious" if the OP already pointed that for her audience he wants to "drop the using of IE6 to browse my website"?

Comment: @Miguel, since your country is Brazil I think you tried it: http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-BR-monthly-201005-201105. So, 1.93% seen to be much more ignorable.

Comment: +1 for a **death to ie** question. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In asp.net you can look at the `Request.Browser` in `Session_start` and do what you want from there. Perhaps Response.Redirect("www.getfirefox.com")

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var browser = Request.Browser;
    if (browser.browser == "Whatever IE is" 
        && browser.version == "your least fave version" )
        Response.Redirect("www.getfirefox.com");
}
```

See msdn for the [httpbrowsercapabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilities%28VS.80%29.aspx) class

You may want to show a banner on your website. Microsoft are running a campaign to get people off IE. Check out http://www.theie6countdown.com/ the banner is on http://www.theie6countdown.com/join-us.aspx

As others will no doubt answer there are many ways to detect browser version.

Conditional css comments

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
```

and Javascript

```
alert( BrowserDetect.browser + ' ' + BrowserDetect.version);
```

are 2 other ways.

Answer (score 3):

If you want, this can be done also with conditional comments:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "someplace.html";

    // Or maybe suggest other things, i.e. a browser upgrade, installing Chrome Frame etc.
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the [user agent header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) and if it is IE 6 redirect to a specific page.

[Here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/) is a handy list of IE user agent strings, grouped by version.